# SailsJS One to Many associations

Tags: node.js, associations, sails.js, waterline

Hi I'm building a Sails app with a couple of models in a one to many configuration. I've been able to create new instances of the models via the relationship, but it seems to be only working one way.

For reference (one) project can have (many) users.

```
/** Projects.js **/
name: {
    type: string
},

managers: {
    collection: 'Users',
    via: 'projects'
}

/** User.js **/
username: { 
    type: 'string'
},

projects { {
    model: 'Projects'
}
```

Using the following create method, results in the User have a reference to the Project, but no reference to the user is available to the Project. The managers reference is an array of user ids.

```
Project.create({ name: req.param('name'), managers: req.param('managers') }).exec(function newProject(err, results) {
    if (err) return res.json({ error: err });
    return res.json({ results: results });
});
```

And to retrieve the projects with their respective managers:

```
Project.findOne({ id: req.param('id') }).populate('managers').exec(function project(err, results) {
    if (err) return res.json({ error: err });
    return res.json({ results: results });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to retrieve a project with its associated users, and the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
managers: {
    collection: 'Users',
    via: 'projects'
}
```

be like this:

```
managers: {
    collection: 'User',
    via: 'projects'
}
```

?...

You refer the collection to the Model filename.
[Refer to this documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.html)